# How can I fix NavigationLink bug?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                //MARK: - CustomTopBar
                HStack {
                    Button(action: { }) { Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3").foregroundColor(.white).font(.title) }.padding(.leading)
                        
                    Spacer()
                        
                    Image("customImage")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(height: 70)
                }
                .background(Color.blue)
                .frame(height: 70)
                    
                //MARK: - MainContent
                List {
                    NavigationLink("ToView1", destination: Text("View1"))
                
                    NavigationLink("ToView2", destination: Text("View2"))
                }
                .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

When I hide default NavigationBar and use custom one I get NavigationLink bug.
If I go to View1 and then return to the MainView, NavigationLink remains pressed.[image]
Tested on iOS 13, 14

Comment: Works well in ios-15 as is. You could try adding ".isDetailLink(false)" to the NavigationLinks.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it seems that NavigationLinks get buggy inside lists.

### Option 1

Try setting to your navigation view the following:

```swift
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

### Option 2

If you app is above ios14 you could use LazyVStack instead of List.

### Option 3

Set a NavigationLink outside the list and make the items in the list as Buttons in the action handler you could do something like this"

```swift
struct SomeView: View {
@State var isActive: Bool = false
@State var selectedView: Int = 1

 var body: some View {
   NavigationView {
    VStack {
     List {
      Button(action: {
       selectedView = 1
       isActive = true
      }){
       Text("View 1")
      }
      Button(action: {
       selectedView = 2
       isActive = true
      }){
       Text("View 2")
      }
     }

    //HERE GOES THE NAV LINK
      NavigationLink(
    "Purple",
    destination: selectedView == 1 ? Text("view 2") : Text("destination 2"),
    isActive: $isActive)
    }
   }
 }

}
```

It is not the most elegant answer but it's one workaround i've found that helped.